# I'm trying to display total no. of orders by each vendor every year?

Tags: mysql, sql

**I'm trying to display total no. of orders by each vendor every year?**

[Table: Sales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjl2G.png)

[Table: Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQz5Y.png)

[Table: Vendors & Vendor_Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCIQ3.png)

```
select year(orderdate) as date_year,count(orderid) as count, OrderID 
from products 
NATURAL JOIN sales 
NATURAL JOIN vendor_info 
WHERE products.Vendor_Id=vendor_info.Vendor_Id  
group by year(orderdate);
```

on doing this query i'm getting

[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHhWN.png)

Where am i going wrong ? and what would the most efficient way to do this?

```
-- Table structure for table `products`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `Product_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `OrderId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Manufacture_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Raw_Material` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Vendor_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Product_id`),
  KEY `OrderId` (`OrderId`)
);

-- Table structure for table `sales`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales` (
  `OrderID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `OrderDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `OrderPrice` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OrderQuantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CustomerName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OrderID`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

-- Table structure for table `Vendors`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Vendors` (
  `Raw_material` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Vendors` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Vendor_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `Vendor_id` (`Vendor_id`)
)

-- Table structure for table `Vendor_info`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Vendor_info` (
  `Vendor_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Vendor_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `Vendor_id` (`Vendor_id`)
)
```

Comment: There is no good reason to use natural joins use explicit joins with ON

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't use images to show sample data and code. Instead please put the text directly into your question. If you indent a block of text by four spaces it will show as a code or data block.  Please [edit] your question. And, please read this. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056

Comment: 1) JOIN multiplying will give wrong aggregate result, try to use COUNT(DISTINCT). 2) Your WHERE is already provided by NATURAL JOIN and hence is excess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the number or orders by vendor and year yoy can use a query like this one:

```
select vendor_info.vendor_name,year(sales.orderdate),count(distinct products.orderId)
from vendor_info 
    join products on vendor_info.vendor_id=productos.vendor_id
    join sales on products.orderid=sales.orderid
group by vendor_info.vendor_name,year(sales.orderdate)
```

Where you make a join from vendors to products and sales. Here you will get only the vendors who have sales.

Answer (score 1):

Some guesswork here, because you have not explained your requirement.

I guess you want to summarize numbers of orders by year.  You can do that with a simpler query than your example, because all the data you need is in your `sales` table.

```
  select year(orderdate) as date_year, count(orderid) as count
    from sales
   group by year(orderdate);
```

If this does not meet your need, please edit your question to give us more details.

Comment: This is exactly what I have been thinking: why to join all these tables when the fields relevant from the output's perspective seem to be in one table!

Comment: also wanted to add the same of vendor or vendor id....

Comment: @AnikSarkerAkash then you should have added that requirement to the question, not to a comment...